# Access website on local xampp server from iphone

Tags: iphone, xampp, htdocs

I have made a website and am hosting it on xampp. I cannot get it to display on my iPhone to test it - the file is in htdocs in another folder

What url do I need to enter into my iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

Where is the server located? Is it on a local network? Is the phone connected to the same network over WIFI? If yes then the server's local ip-address would be a good starting point for an URL.

Is the server running on the internet? Then use its global IP address or set up a dns record.

Is the server running locally and your phone is **not** connected to the local network? Then you need to access it using your external IP address. And make sure your firewall is open, and that port forwarding is set up correctly.

Comment: The server is located on my PC using the local network (home wifi) and my phone is also connected to that wifi

Which IP should I be using and how can I get that? Also is the firewall an issue on local network that both are connected to?

Answer (score 0):

You can access pages from a iPhone by either typing http ://ip or http://local_dns_name

As long as the iPhone is on the network correctly (on WIFI, not 3G/4G connection) you should be able to access all local resources.